# custom django signal receiver not being called wagtail code

Tags: django, wagtail

We have a custom receiver connecting to the task_submitted signal in a project app.
I have verified that the receiver is added to the dispatcher receivers
Locally the receiver is invoked, however when deployed to our staging evnvironment in cloud foundry in a docker container the receiver is not invoked
According to a log the self.receivers is None when invoking the dispatcher.send method
?

Comment: Where is your custom receiver located and where is the file containing your signal imported? This sounds to me like in dev the receiver is getting populated on a reload not on startup. Can you reproduce the problem locally by setting DEBUG=False?

Comment: I think it was a matter of defining scope of signal, I have it working now

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved by defining the signal receiver at global scope rather than local scope